# Convert seconds to days , hh:mm:ss C#

Tags: c#, timespan

I need to convert seconds in the format `3d, 02:05:45`. With the below function I could convert it to `3.02:05:45`. I'm not sure how to convert it to the format I wanted. Please help.

```
private string ConvertSecondsToDate(string seconds)
{
    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(seconds));

    if (t.Days > 0)
        return t.ToString(@"d\.hh\:mm\:ss");
    return t.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

}
```

If I try to do something like this return `t.ToString(@"%d , hh\:mm\:ss")` I'm getting an error,

> input string is not in correct format.

Comment: u can add ur desire character in toString Method with "\" before ur character ==> t.ToString(@"d\d\,hh\:mm\:ss")

Comment: can you give an example? Are you meaning this return t.ToString(@"%., hh:mm:ss") ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can espace `d` character and additional white space with `\` like;

```
if (t.Days > 0)
    return t.ToString(@"d\d\,\ hh\:mm\:ss");
```

or

```
if (t.Days > 0)
    return t.ToString(@"d'd, 'hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Result will be formatted as `3d, 02:05:45`

From [Other Characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Other) section in [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Any other unescaped character in a format string, **including a
>   white-space character**, is interpreted as a custom format specifier. In
>   most cases, the presence of any other unescaped character results in a
>   FormatException.
>
> There are **two ways** to include a literal character in a format string:
>
> - Enclose it in single quotation marks (the literal string delimiter).
> - Precede it with a backslash ("\"), which is interpreted as an escape character. This means that, in C#, the format string must
>     either be @-quoted, or the literal character must be preceded by an
>     additional backslash.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx

> Any [other] unescaped character in a format string, including a
>   white-space character, is interpreted as a custom format specifier. In
>   most cases, the presence of any other unescaped character results in a
>   FormatException. There are two ways to include a literal character in
>   a format string:
>
> - Enclose it in single quotation marks (the literal
>     string delimiter).
> - Precede it with a backslash ("\"), which is
>     interpreted as an escape character. This means that, in C#, the format
>     string must either be @-quoted, or the literal character must be
>     preceded by an additional backslash.

```
private string ConvertSecondsToDate(string seconds)
{
     TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(seconds));

     if (t.Days > 0)
         return t.ToString(@"d\d\,\ hh\:mm\:ss");
     return t.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
}
```

Or

```
 if (t.Days > 0)
     return t.ToString(@"d'd, 'hh':'mm':'ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return t.ToString(@"d\d\, hh\:mm\:ss")
```